# What does the "DATE" in date_sub(DATE string, int) do?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I came across the following line and could not understand why it works.

```
where cast(date_str as date) between date_sub(date '{start_date_str}', 28) 
and date_sub(date '{start_date_str}', 1)
```

According to Hive docs, the 1st parameter of `date_sub` should be a string. So why does the author explicitly put a `date` keyword in front of the 2 strings?

Is `wanted_type expr` syntax sugar for type conversion? According to the Hive docs, the correct syntax for casting should be `cast(expr as wanted_type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question.
I have just updated the [LanguageManual UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) page

---

1. The ISO/ANSI way to note a date literal is `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`
2. At the beginning of Hive the `date`  type was not supported so the date functions used `string` arguments.
3. It seems the documentation was out of date and currently `date_add` and `date_sub` except `string`, `date` and `timestamp` as first argument.

[GenericUDFDateSub.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFDateSub.java)

```
.
.
.
public class GenericUDFDateSub extends GenericUDFDateAdd {
  private transient SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  public GenericUDFDateSub() {
    this.signModifier = -1;
  }
.
.
.
```

[GenericUDFDateAdd.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFDateAdd.java)

```
.
.
.
switch (inputType1) {
case STRING:
case VARCHAR:
case CHAR:
  inputType1 = PrimitiveCategory.STRING;
  dateConverter = ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(
    (PrimitiveObjectInspector) arguments[0],
    PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
  break;
case TIMESTAMP:
  dateConverter = new TimestampConverter((PrimitiveObjectInspector) arguments[0],
    PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableTimestampObjectInspector);
  break;
case DATE:
  dateConverter = ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(
    (PrimitiveObjectInspector) arguments[0],
    PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableDateObjectInspector);
  break;
default:
  throw new UDFArgumentException(
    " DATE_ADD() only takes STRING/TIMESTAMP/DATEWRITABLE types as first argument, got "
    + inputType1);
}
.
.
.
```